# Remove buttons or title bar from Visualforce page header in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, global-actions

I created a Visualforce page and put it into Salesforce1 using global action. The page automatically comes with a header bar with save/cancel button. How do I remove that? I tried `showheader="false"` in the VisualForce page, and the header still shows.

My Visualforce Page looks something like

```
<apex:page controller="MobileSearchParcel" showHeader="false">
    <h3 class="card-header"><span class="header-label">Parcel Search</span></h3>
    <apex:form > 
        // My form goes here
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

These are the button I want to get rid of on my Salesforce1,

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: After re-reading the pdf found out a way to use the save button using the publisher.js file. But still haven't found a way to hide the buttons...

Answer (score 8):

In Summer '15 you'll be able to hide the header in Visualforce custom actions using the showQuickActionVfHeader attribute. As per the [Summer '15 Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/custom_actions_vf_pages_remove_pub_header.htm):

> To hide the header, add showQuickActionVfHeader=“false” to the
>   <apex:page> tag of the custom action’s
>   Visualforce page. When the Visualforce custom action renders in
>   Salesforce1, the header and the Cancel and Save buttons are hidden.
>   Using this attribute doesn’t affect how the action displays in the
>   full Salesforce site.
>
> If you don’t specify showQuickActionVfHeader, its value defaults to
>   true.
>
> The showQuickActionVfHeader attribute isn’t supported in communities.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things to consider. I am sorry I don't have enough points to comment, so I am writing as Answer.

1. If you are using Object in the page, try removing edit access to the Object. Not a promising solution, sometime works!
2. I used your Visualforce code to create a page and created a Visualforce tab in my org and added the tab in Salesforce1 Navigation Menu. I was able to open the page without any Save and Cancel buttons.

Let me know if it helps! Cheers!